# How to get count of the nonzero values while calculating average

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `mytable` with the following structure and data (Oracle 11g)

```
Job_name    job_execution_time(JET in seconds)   Run_Date           records_processed
A1             0                                 7/1/2013           0
A1             0                                 7/5/2013           0
A1             3                                 7/12/2013          5
A1             9                                 7/22/2013          14
A1             0                                 8/1/2013           0
A1            15                                 8/16/2013          20 
A2             0                                 8/15/2013          0     
A2             0                                 8/17/2013          0
A2            10                                 9/15/2013          25
A2            45                                 9/17/2013          70
```

I am trying to get the average(ignoring '0' values) of the (JET) column for each job for that specific month. Also I need to get a count of the non-zero values which I am using for my average calculation.
For example:
For job `A1` for the month of `July`, the average of the JET column will be `(9+3)/2 = 6` and the count of the nonzero values used for the calculation of this average would be `2`.
I got the average value using the following code but have problem getting the count.

```
select job_name , to_char(Run_Date, 'Month') Mon ,
       nvl(avg(nullif(job_execution_time,0)), 0) Average_secs
from mytable
group by job_name, to_char(Run_Date, 'Month')
```

How can I get the count of the nonzero values which are used for the calculation of every average? I tried the following for count but does not work.

- `count(nullif(job_execution_time, 0)) count_nonzeros`
- `sum(CASE nvl(job_execution_time, 0) !=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Count_NonZeros"`

Thanks.

Comment: Your sum should work, but I think the syntax is missing a WHEN: sum(CASE WHEN nvl(job_execution_time, 0) != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing 'When'. I added it but it gives the correct count only for the first job it displays in the grid. The count values for the other subsequent jobs are incorrect.

Comment: If it's possible, please add your final query with `sum` syntax in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM and CASE statement

```
select job_name , to_char(Run_Date, 'Month') Mon ,
       nvl(avg(nullif(job_execution_time,0)), 0) Average_secs, 
       sum(case when job_execution_time !=0 then 1 else 0 end) counts
       from table1 group by job_name, to_char(Run_Date, 'Month');
```